# Should I have to sumit jobs to spark or I can run them from client lib?

Tags: database, apache-spark, hadoop

So I'm learning about Spark and I have a question about how client libs works.

My goal is to do some sort of data analysis in Spark, telling it where are the data sources (databases, cvs, etc) to process, and store results in hdfs, s3 or any kind of database like MariaDB or MongoDB.

I though about having a service (API application) that "tells" spark what I want to do. The question is: Is it enough setting the master configuration with `spark:remote-host:7077` at context creation or should I send the application to spark with some sort of `spark-submit` command?

Answer (score 0):

This completely depends on how your environment is set up, if all paths are linked to your account you should be able to run one of the two commands, to efficiently open the shell and run test commands. The reason to have a shell, is this will allow you to dynamically run commands and validate/learn how to run/tether commands onto one another and see what results come out.

Scala

```
spark-shell
```

Python

```
pyspark
```

Inside of the environment, if everything is linked to Hive tables you can check the tables by running

```
spark.sql("show tables").show(100,false)
```

The above command will run a "show tables" on the Spark-Hive-Metastore Catalogue and will return all active tables you can see (doesn't mean you can access the underlying data). The 100 means I am going to look at 100 rows and the false means to show the full string not the first N many characters.

In a mythical example if one of the tables you see is called Input_Table you can bring it into the environmrnt with the below commands

```
val inputDF = spark.sql("select * from Input_Table")
inputDF.count
```

I would heavily advise, while your learning, not to run the commands via Spark-Submit, because you will need to pass through the Class and Jar, forcing you to edit/rebuild for each testing making it difficult to figure how commands will run without have a lot of down time.

Comment: Hi @Afeldman, thanks for your replay. 

So I understand from what you say that in a production environment I should compile the jobs and submit them to the cluster, isn't it? 

My concerns come from the following: If I execute the jobs "remotely", is it the program being sent to the cluster or is it using the caller's machine in someway?

For example, If I run a job locally to retrieve a cvs to cross data with a database, all that retrieval and calculations will be perform on the cluster or is it my machine related to do so?

Thank you again in advance!

Comment: (1) Yes, I would advise only running compiled jobs via jars, unless you have a critical one-time need to do an action on shell.

(2) This is slightly complicated, so to reduce complexity I am going to say you are just doing a 'select *' from the database table [background reason is that Spark will leverage the DB, at times, to do some calculations during input]. When you build a Spark-shell (or submit), you designate two groups Driver and Executor Nodes. [Continued in next comment]

Comment: Whenever you call an action, it will pull the data into Spark and will run all actions within your session. To help the Driver will initially hold a majority of the data for persistence and catalog purposes, whereas local actions in partitions are stored in executors.